# nginx 1.15.8 loses TLS 1.3 after gcc 8 installation

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl, gcc, g++

I run a centos 7.6 server with nginx. Centos repos do not have latest nginx, so I compiled manually using instructions from [here](https://blog.bejarano.io/enabling-tls13-support-in-nginx.html).

This left me a nginx binary:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.15.8
built by gcc 7.2.0 
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --with-pcre=/n/pcre-8.42 --with-openssl=/n/openssl-1.1.1a --with-zlib=/n/zlib-1.2.11 --with-file-aio --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-threads
```

which worked with TLS 1.3.

However I installed gcc 8.2 as well from https://cbs.centos.org/.
It installed correctly, and I tried to rebuild nginx with the new compiler. Still the same output, still the same binary, but no TLS 1.3. Chrome says it is a TLS 1.2 connection, SSLlabs says no tls 1.3 support.

I tried recompiling with gcc 7.2.0, still same result.

What could be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Remember that nginx publish their own CentOS repos, and you can use those.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes but not compiled against latest OpenSSL.

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't another version of nginx that is running on the system?

Answer (score 0):

This should not depend on gcc but on ssl library.

I can suggest the following:

- Make sure `--with-openssl=/n/openssl-1.1.1a` still points to correct openssl.
- Check which ssl library is nginx linked with: `ldd $(which nginx)` should point to your version of openssl rather than system-wide one.
- You may need to recompile openssl and nginx to make sure everything is dandy.

Comment: [root@server ~]# ldd $(which nginx)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffec67a4000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1db4c0d000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1db49f1000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f1db47ba000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1db43ed000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1db4e11000)
        libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007f1db41ea000)

It seems to have been built statically with openssl.

Comment: Interesting. What does `nginx -V` says?

Comment: built with OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018